# Connection closed by peer Retrofit

Tags: android

i develop an application the communicate with my server through API and i use Retrofit library, the app was working fine on my Kit-Kat mobile, but now i get 
`HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer` from Retrofit logger and i know cannot do anything with the server
Kindly help, thanks for advance

does the problem exist because i use shared hosting?

here is what i am getting in Logcat
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyCPb.png)

Comment: Are you having any proxy applications running anywhere in the entire system?

Comment: i don't understand the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Kit Kat devices don't have TLS 1.2 enabled or installed at all. Either use older version on your backend or enable it in your app.

To add support for TLS 1.2 you should have Google Play services and do this in your `Application` class in `onCreate` method:

```
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this)
} catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(this, e.connectionStatusCode)
} catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
    Timber.e(e)
}
```

And to make sure it's enabled on all devices use:

```
class Tls12SocketFactory(private val delegate: SSLSocketFactory) : SSLSocketFactory() {
    companion object {
        private val trustManager by lazy {
            val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
            trustManagerFactory.init(null as KeyStore?)
            trustManagerFactory.trustManagers
                .first { it is X509TrustManager } as X509TrustManager
        }

        fun OkHttpClient.Builder.enableTls12() = apply {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                try {
                    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2.javaName())
                    sslContext.init(null, arrayOf(trustManager), null)

                    sslSocketFactory(Tls12SocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory), trustManager)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Timber.e(e, "Error while setting TLS 1.2 compatibility")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun Socket.patchForTls12(): Socket {
        return (this as? SSLSocket)?.apply {
            enabledProtocols += TlsVersion.TLS_1_2.javaName()
        } ?: this
    }

    override fun getDefaultCipherSuites(): Array<String> {
        return delegate.defaultCipherSuites
    }

    override fun getSupportedCipherSuites(): Array<String> {
        return delegate.supportedCipherSuites
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun createSocket(s: Socket, host: String, port: Int, autoClose: Boolean): Socket? {
        return delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose)
            .patchForTls12()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, UnknownHostException::class)
    override fun createSocket(host: String, port: Int): Socket? {
        return delegate.createSocket(host, port)
            .patchForTls12()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, UnknownHostException::class)
    override fun createSocket(host: String, port: Int, localHost: InetAddress, localPort: Int): Socket? {
        return delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort)
            .patchForTls12()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun createSocket(host: InetAddress, port: Int): Socket? {
        return delegate.createSocket(host, port)
            .patchForTls12()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun createSocket(address: InetAddress, port: Int, localAddress: InetAddress, localPort: Int): Socket? {
        return delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort)
            .patchForTls12()
    }
}
```

Then use it when creating `OkHttpClient` like this:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .enableTls12()
            .build()
```

Comment: Second is just a class for itself so it goes in new file. Third one goes in the code where you construct `OkHttpClient` and pass it to `Retrofit`(usually it's a Dagger module if you are using Dagger). If you aren't making your own `OkHttpClient` just make it before you construct `Retrofit` instance and pass it to retrofit builder

Comment: is that code right? i write code with java and the class you gave me is in kotlin so i have conflict here
`private static  OkHttpClient.Builder okBuilder = Tls12SocketFactory.Companion.enableTls12(new OkHttpClient.Builder());`

Comment: Yep, that's it. Just don't forget `okBuilder.build()`

Comment: i just had to change the super class of my application class to be MultidexApplication class, do you have any clues for that?

Comment: It is usually when you APK has more than 65536 methods(including libraries you are depending on) it needs to be split into multiple dex files(format that containes compiled classes).

Comment: and will it affect my application?

Comment: Users won't really notice any difference. It's just a way of packaging Android apps.

Comment: okay, and for the TLS, should i enable it for every app i create using Retrofit?

Comment: If you are going to support Android 4.4 or lower, yes, if not you probably don't need it.

Comment: but this problem also exist when testing on Android 7.0

Comment: I'm not sure then. Use it always.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set TLS enabled from the server side.